# A/B testing the sticky vote controls

Tags: discussion, voting, experimental

First, apologies for not creating this feedback thread earlier - in hindsight, a change to such an established feature of our sites really does warrant some explanation.

We're running an [A/B test](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/A/B_testing) on Stack Overflow only that places half of registered users with >= 15 reputation in a variant group that will see voting controls like so (shamelessly stolen from [ᔕᖺᘎᕊ's answer here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/35041/move-the-vote-button/254795#254795)):

---

[image: sticky vote controls example]

---

A few points about this current experiment:

- If you're in the variant group, the controls will only move if you can vote on the post; your own posts will not have the sticky controls
- This will run for another three weekdays, so it should finish up next Wednesday, 2015-06-10.
- We've set acceptance criteria at 5% more voting than the baseline.
- After the experiment concludes, I'll update this question with the results.

**Edit** 2015-06-08 01:50

We're into the next variant with these changes, based on feedback:

- stickiness is applied if the post's body is longer than 2/3 of the browser window's viewport
- stickiness is applied regardless of a post's votability, e.g. the controls will be sticky on your own posts (if they're long enough)

**Edit** 2015-06-09 19:55

Experiment has completed; preparing a summary.

**Edit** 2015-06-12 18:30

TL;DR **this feature will not be implemented**, as it had too little of an impact on voting.

We ran two* variants of these sticky voting controls:

1. [variant 1 results](http://butisitstatisticallysignificant.com/#Baseline=61465%2C1568524&Sticky+vote+controls+1=58364%2C1548801&abba%3AintervalConfidenceLevel=0.95&abba%3AuseMultipleTestCorrection=true): movement was only enabled on posts you could vote on; no minimum height requirement to the post body; **~3.8% vote loss from baseline**
2. [variant 2 results](http://butisitstatisticallysignificant.com/#Baseline=57514%2C1686614&Sticky+vote+controls+2=58775%2C1687966&abba%3AintervalConfidenceLevel=0.95&abba%3AuseMultipleTestCorrection=true): movement was enabled on all posts if you had at least 15 rep; post body height had to be longer than 2/3 of the viewport; **~2.1% vote gain from baseline**

Some definitions for the above result links:

- baseline: the current behavior, i.e. voting controls do not move from their initial placement
- trial: a question page was rendered to a user who could at least upvote something on the page
- success: the user upvoted or downvoted one of the question or answers

We placed a 5% minimum improvement threshold for acceptance; this is completely arbitrary, but it's a common floor in our experiments, as new features == new upkeep. Also, judging from the extreme polarization of the responses to this feature, we would need a user preference to disable it, something we're hesitant to provide for any feature.

Going forward, we might try another experiment with duplicating the controls at the bottom of long posts, but there's no ETA for this.

If you did like the functionality, it can be added via [ᔕᖺᘎᕊ's Stack Overflow Extras (SOX) script](https://stackapps.com/questions/6091/se-additional-optional-features).

<sub>* an initial variant was stopped after only an hour and [this change was applied](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/257910/dont-move-vote-buttons-past-the-bottom-of-the-post)</sub>

Comment: This is the only time I've wished I had 125 points on meta. If you deploy this, please add an option to turn it off.

Comment: I already gave my feedback: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/258034/keep-moderator-post-links-next-to-vote-buttons

Comment: Just curious, was this change sitting in a drawer for long time just waiting for someone to ask for it, or was is an ultra spontaneous decision?

Comment: I take it that it's the A/B test results ("is there 5% more voting?") which you'll use as your "feedback". So what kind of feedback are you looking for in answers to this meta-question?

Comment: Yikes! Now my cheese is not only moving but also chasing me across the page! Can't seem to like it, it seems.

Comment: This is good for blocking bot users. There's incident in Math.SE where many questions get downvoted and number of downvoted questions increasing rapidly. See this http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/20661/nearly-all-frontpage-questions-downvoted?cb=1

Comment: "We've set acceptance criteria at 5% more voting than the baseline." is there any basis for this percentage? Shouldn't the acceptance criteria be "any improvement and no significant complaints"?

Comment: In which sites are you rolling the change? I noticed the sticky vote button yesterday when browsing StackOverflow site in my PC. Also, which browser/device will support it? Today I browse Meta an SO in iPad2 (tried Safari & Chrome) but cannot see the sticky button anymore. Have I been kicked from the variant group, or is my browser and device combination incompatible, or was it just my hallucination yesterday? :O

Comment: think its a step in the right direction but more background/ context would be helpful. have there been internal se discussions about (how to) increase voting? or maybe they have occured but are preferred to be "off the record"? and does that 5% also incl negative votes?

Comment: I will be short on it: I HATED IT! This is exactly what I hate. It feels like it is begging to vote. Like those awful adds on some websites that follow you, screaming "CLICK ME! CLICK ME! NOTICE ME!".

Comment: I like it - it reduces scroll time on the really long posts (which are often the most vote-worthy).

Comment: @aff From the beginning of the second paragraph "We're running an A/B test on **StackOverflow**" emphasis mine.

Comment: @usr the 5% improvement for acceptance is mostly arbitrary on our part; too little of an improvement and it's not worth the maintenance costs.  Also, if we have to have a setting for users to disable a feature, that's additional overhead.

Comment: @JarrodDixon THEN DON'T DEPLY IT. Please! Before deploying new features, you could showcase them and figure out if the users want it. But before that, you could solve the existing bugs first.

Comment: I like it personally. I sometimes write books (well, maybe short stories) as answers. I'll get a ton more up votes this way! :D J/K! I do like the idea though. I'm a firm believer in voting ... it's what makes the SE work. If there is some simple way to remind people to vote, we should do it. This is simple and innocuous. *Get 'er Done!*

Comment: What is that *horrible* animation supposed to do for us? Stop it, please!

Comment: What does "_acceptance criteria at 5% more voting than the baseline_" mean? What kind of feedback do you want, exactly, so that you can compute percentages?

Comment: Oh! Please no! I will quit each and every stackexchange site to which I belong if this migraine-inducing POS (piece of excrement) comes to pass.

Comment: @IsmaelMiguel 
As always when some new feature is added to a product, the "fix existing bugs first" complaint is fallacious. Just because they're adding this it does not mean they are not working on other bugs, nor that the advantage of adding this would not be greater than those of fixing other bugs.

Comment: @nico I assure you that some bugs aren't even touched or looked at. One of them is the bug when you edit a comment on Internet Explorer. It has been posted by me and another user (mine was deemed duplicated, as obvious) and NOTHING has been done. Literally NOTHING. And it is a nasty bug. Another bug is the syntax highlighter crapping out in PHP (when using heredocs and nowdocs) and Javascript (when using regexes).

Comment: @IsmaelMiguel again, your reasoning is fallacious. Are the people working at this the same that are supposed to be working at the IE bug? Would they work at that bug if they were not working at this? Is that bug affecting a sufficient amount of people to be worth investing time solving? And so on... Unless you work at SO it's difficult to judge these things, as we most likely don't have the larger picture. It's absolutely fine if you don't like the *scrolly votey thingy*. I am just saying that "solve bugs first" is irrelevant here, as the discussion is on "do you like the *scrolly thingy*".

Comment: @nico No, they aren't the same people because no one is working on that bug. And, according to another comment, they only care if this increases the number of votes made, not if we like it or not. And, from another comment, I can understand that this won't have an option to be disabled.

Comment: I just want to say, now that I'm over the initial shock and stare of this, I think it is an amazing feature and hope that it doesn't go away. I love it so much and it's almost like it offers a sense of security knowing those buttons are always right there when I need them. Don't change a thing :)

Comment: Gahfkdafndsjnvsdknvksdnsdflaggghhhhhhhh!!!! Stop harassing me with my seemingly horrible well deserved down votes!

Comment: Agree with @Praetorian.  Please at least make it optional/configurable.

Comment: I noticed this he other day but it seemed like not all of the vote counters/mechanisms moved. I tried several questions on the SO site and I could never figure out why some worked and why some didn't. Should have gone into *Inspect Element* I suppose. FWIW, once it works correctly I think it is a great idea.

Comment: @Jeeped Posts you can't vote on (your own, locked, etc) don't have scrolling controls. We're thinking of changing that, but not before the current experiment ends.

Comment: This doesn't work well in w3m and lynx. Not that it ever worked well in w3m.

Comment: Somebody in this thread *really* hates A/B tests.

Comment: While I see the point about introducing a moving element to a page that so far has been delightfully static when scrolling, I don't hate the new feature. It's probably going to be more useful than anything else. Those who really hate it can always get rid of it through a userscript.

Comment: Awesome job, I actually like it.

Comment: Kind of curious: the controls were normal for me when the test started, but then they started moving yesterday. Today I checked again, and they are not moving anymore. So am I in the variant group?

Comment: Can it be made to blink too? Maybe with a marquee border around it.

Comment: I haven't gotten a chance to try this, it seems like it could be useful, but instead of following why not just permanently fix all vote buttons to the bottom of the post instead of the top? You're expected to read the post anyway before voting (at least I think you are), so it seems to address the "I don't feel like scrolling up" premise without the stickiness that some find irritating. On the other hand it's useful to have the *score* at the top so maybe this comment isn't the greatest idea. But people whine about score affecting votes anyways, so maybe score fixed to top, buttons bottom...

Comment: If people want to vote an  answer/question it does not matter where the vote button is.

Comment: It makes skimming through long questions and answer harder, especially when searching backwards for some kind of information that I knew was there, because I can't use the voting buttons as an indicator that I have reached the top of a post. But at least it looks cool.

Comment: I can confirm that the vote button does not become sticky when browsing SO in iPad2 (tried Safari & Chrome). Is it not applicable in mobile or just _not yet_ supported?

Comment: Although I was in the test group, the functionality no longer works for me.

Comment: I think it's kind of distracting. I like that I don't have to scroll to the top of the post to vote, but if the vote controls could be made slightly transparent or otherwise less prominent while scrolling it would be far better.

Comment: Re http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/258048/a-b-testing-the-sticky-vote-controls-give-your-feedback-please?cb=1#comment841672_258048, it is working now. Big improvement with the short posts not having the jumping about. With that gone, perhaps the "OH! the Pain!" people will have less to offend them? I can imagine that many questions with their answers now won't have any stickiness at all.

Comment: "_stickiness is applied regardless of a post's votability, e.g. the controls will be sticky on your own posts (if they're long enough)_" -- Why does this apply for our posts? We can't vote for our own posts.

Comment: So I'm in the group with the floating controls and ... I didn't even notice the change until I saw it pointed out here. So I guess it's fine. My only comment, now that I'm actually observant, is that I don't think they should follow you down if the entire answer can fit on the screen. (**EDIT:** On further use, this seems to be the goal, actually, but it's not 100% there.) But for really long answers, this seems helpful; now I can vote from the bottom of the answer instead of scrolling back up.

Comment: Does the 5% improvement have to apply to all votes in total or just those where the animation happens? The former seems a bit unfair, since only a small number of posts actually have this effect.

Comment: Looks really cool, but it's usefulness is limited. Like for example, if I have already DV/UV'd it, I don't need to see it sliding with the Q/A anymore. At that point it just becomes a useless distraction.

Comment: I honestly didn't even notice it until I saw this post, and realized that I am indeed in the treatment group.

Comment: earlier on was looking cool feature but now since SE is testing it.. with each visit I am finding it more and more distracting - hope there will be option to turn it off

Comment: I seem to fall into the variant group, just saw the oddly scrolling vote buttons.  Result: I find them distraction, annoying, and strongly prefer the old behaviour.

Comment: What problem is this solving? Is there a need to read a post and evaluate the vote element at the same time? No. FULL STOP If the post doesn't span than the entire page you can read the votes. Posts that span more than the entire screen are rare. In a bizarre case where you need to read a long post and know the votes at the same time, then you also have the ability to remember a single number. Furthermore this is breaking the UI since the votes element is positioned at the start of the post and serves as a "visual lock" that helps locating the start of a post when scanning the page.

Comment: @2501 of course it's solving a problem - the need to scroll back up after reading a longer post.

Comment: @JasonC I would like to see you post your comment (vote buttons at the end, with the score optionally repeated or only displayed at the top) as an answer. This would very simply satisfy all those who say they prefer not to scroll back to the top to vote, without annoying the people who don't like it, and there is nothing to be gained by facilitating voting by those who have not read the whole answer. static placement is also less likely to have platform-dependent problems. KIS.

Comment: @sdenham Good call, I've done so.

Comment: FYI: this is a horrible way to get feed back.  Isn't there a survey page you could create with 5 options ranging from love it to hate it and a place to enter comments?  Just do one for each iteration (so people who hate the old version do not get counted against people who love the new).

Comment: @Pëkka Scrolling back up could be good or bad. You haven't demonstrated that that is an actual problem that needs solving.

Comment: This is too distracting!  Do not force this on everyone.

Comment: That's an amazing idea and is definitely needed. It's totally non-intrusive and should help a great deal to remind users to actually vote. And we need users to vote! To everyone who sees that as an annoying ad for more voting, of course it is (well, just that it isn't annoying at all), since that's what is required as, well, users don't friggin' vote enough! I can't see who's distracted by little moving thingy, maybe the first second you see it, but after that it immediately goes into flesh and blood. Of course it isn't needed by people who actually *do* vote, but well...

Comment: @Pëkka *"of course it's solving a problem - the need to scroll back up after reading a longer post."* - Even more than that, the need to *remember* to scroll back up in the first place.

Comment: Seems that the implementation is a bit buggy -- the sticky controls work on my home PC (even through RDP) but not on my work PC. Both of them use the latest version of Chrome and at the same resolution in Chrome. And I used [the same answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29801753/combining-generic-methods-and-overloads/29801854#29801854) to test them on each. The only difference is that the work PC has four other monitors. (Though that should have no effect on the browser.)

Comment: Now, for me, it has stopped working again. Is it Wednesday somewhere yet?

Comment: I can only think of one answer where this would have "benefited." [And it was arguably a joke answer](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/280393/give-an-option-to-wear-multiple-hats/280456#280456).

Comment: This feature where the buttons below the scroll the page is valuable primarily in long questions and answers, so we come to the end of text need not go back to the beginning to vote and thus below to read the next answer, very valuable.

Comment: @EBrown inclusion in the split test isn't based solely on your user id, but also your ip address and user agent.

Comment: @JarrodDixon That seems like a less reliable/full way to do it, I don't browse *.SE nearly as often at home as I do at work. That's what my mobile app is for. I would expect to have the same features across both, the fact that I don't have the same features across both home and work just add points to SE's unreliability/undesirability factor for me. I wouldn't have even known I was in the inclusion on my home PC had I not had a [Unicode issue with the Android app](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/258381/android-app-text-encoding-bug-unicode-symbols-dont-display-properly).

Comment: @JarrodDixon Since you only ran the test for a few days, how will you show that effects on voting are due to the floating buttons rather than the attention that this discussion has drawn to the vote buttons in general?

Comment: I think this better get historical lock, or at least closed, no?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this feature was tested and was not implemented. Further feedback on this change is now irrelevant. If it were to be brought up again, should be its own feature request.

Answer (score 225):

I don't like how it's following me. If it does get deployed, I hope there's a setting to turn it off.

Comment: Just for you, we'll make it hiss and explode :P Give it a try for a few days and see if you still feel that way?

Comment: Funnily enough I reckon there'll be a userscript to remove it just as there is currently one to add it. Can't please everybody all the time etc etc.

Comment: First impression is that it is a bit distracting. Maybe it will change with custom.

Comment: @CiroSantilli: Not only is it distracting, I also don't care about the score while I'm reading a post. I'm the kind of user who reads a post entirely, _then_ decide if I want to vote. This bit of feature is fancy, but annoying. I'd rather take screenshots of my favorite paragraphs that doesn't have a random vote counter, than ones that do.

Comment: Agreed. When I scroll, I want to *scroll* without random bits of the page refusing to scroll when requested. I'd rather not see this at all, as I think it's just a bit of gratuitous "because we can" fluff. But if it goes in, I would like a way to turn it off.

Comment: @unihedron: I also prefer to read the entire answer before voting, which is exactly why I think this is a *good* feature; I don't like having to scroll back up to the top of the answer to vote, then back down again to read the next answer. The current implementation looks a bit more jerky (at least on my tablet) than it ideally should, but that's a technical issue that (hopefully) can be fixed.

Comment: @IlmariKaronen: "I don't like having to scroll back up to the top of the answer to vote" - ... You do realize keyboard shortcuts exist, right?...

Comment: +1 for it being distracting. In addition to that, though, I rely on the vote buttons as one of those subtle visual cues which help me to navigate around the page quickly, and making them move has slowed me down.

Comment: @Unihedron Ilmari reports being on a tablet, so keyboard shortcuts actually DON'T exist

Comment: @Zaralynda: I apologize in that case, but the detail of being on a tablet actually missed my read since it was in parenthesis and behind another clause. Scrolling on a tablet or touch display is also easier that scrolling on a trackpad though, and I typically control my Surface well enough to swiftly navigate to posts and vote icons (since, well, sensitivty is configurable), so I'd rather prefer to have them hidden on such devices altogether.

Comment: I agree; I've been dealing with this for a few days and I really kinda hate it. Though I can see how other people might like it, I think an option to disable it would be nice. Otherwise I will have to look into a user script to disable it manually.

Comment: As I explained in [my own post](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/296190/im-not-sure-i-like-the-sticky-score-feature), another reason to dislike the feature is because I was using the place of the arrows on the screen as an indication of where the top of the post was. Now you can no longer see without scrolling back up. I'll be disabling the feature.

Comment: @Zaralynda that is actually not the full site version's concern. Tablet site version should solve the tablet problems. If you try to make a single version solve all problems, nobody is going to be happy.

Comment: @ClickRick That's a good point about the vote counter serving as a visual cue for the start of a new answer. I am not in the test group, but it seems like the vote counters can still function that way even with the change. As you scroll down, you still see the next vote counter come into view. And as you scroll up, the current vote counter stops when it hits its head on the answer above it.

Comment: Hate this thing. Completely distracting; make sure to have a setting to turn it off.

Comment: @GregHewgill the idea is to get more voting. If the controls aren't on-screen for a long answer (which is *all the more worthy* if it's long and someone spent a lot of time on it), how can people remember to vote? Out of sight, out of mind. And long answers / questions are especially penalized by fixed vote controls, which is precisely the opposite of what you'd want.

Comment: @JeffAtwood Long isn't an automatic qualifier for good. Good answers will make people want to vote, so they won't have a problem scrolling back to the top (seriously, you think that's too difficult? It's even easier on mobile) to vote. The kind of people who won't do this because it requires an extra step (scrolling back up) is the kind who will just drive-by and vote anyway because it is a question they've had in the past (see: all the *terrible* questions on Stack Overflow that get +1, +2, +3 votes within minutes).

Comment: @TylerH The entire point of this test is to see if this change *does* get people to vote more. Your statement that "good answers will make people want to vote" is effectively what is being tested (though I would point out that it is not only good answers that need voting; downvotes on bad answers are as important as upvotes on good answers).

Comment: @KRyan No, what's being tested is "will having the vote option visible for the entire duration of the question text translate to more total votes?" It's totally unrelated to quality.

Comment: I despise crap following me around as I scroll.  If you intent is to guarantee that I *NEVER* vote on an answer again because I've added the div with the vote arrows to my content blocker (ABP:  It's not just for ads!) and thus never see the vote buttons again this is a brillant idea.  Otherwise, not so much.  As for other 3rd party ways to make it go away suggested above; not going to happen.  Creating an ABP rule to remove the offensive div would require less work than Googling "What is a user script"; and I'll take the path of least resistance 100 times out of 100.

Comment: @TylerH More voting improves the quality of content. This is one of the fundamental theories behind the entire SE system, and the success of SE strongly suggests that the theory is valid.

Comment: @KRyan voting has no direct influence on the quality of content. If 50 people upvote a question, it doesn't magically get revised. It takes a willful interaction from a user to do that. At best, voting has an indirect influence in that it just gets more views and therefore increases the likelihood that someone will edit it because one of the viewers is bound to be someone who cares about editing low-quality content. The point remains however, that's not related to this feature test, which is purely about keeping voting controls visible while you scroll.

Comment: @TylerH I didn't use the word "direct," because that isn't true. Voting is what makes the site as a whole useful, reliable, and convenient, voting is what establishes accuracy (in theory), and voting is how the site demonstrates to experts that it is a serious place that knows what it is talking about. Voting silences noise and exalts expertise (again, in theory), and that is what drives user engagement, participation, and dedication to maintaining that quality. More votes means greater granularity, greater sensitivity. That improves the site. If that theory failed, the site wouldn't work.

Comment: @KRyan It's implied when you say "X improves Y" without any kind of delimiting. And yes, voting is what drives all the site's mechanisms, which, in turn, enable quality. However, and this is the third time I've had to say this, this A/B test is **not** about improving site quality. It is **only** about driving up the amount of votes, *all else staying the same**. A basic A/B test where only one parameter is changed between two states within two groups to measure a difference.

Comment: Comments aren't really a good place to discuss that.

Comment: Problem: the bottom of a post is the best place to know if you want to upvote it, right after you have finished reading it.  Goal: Provide a way to vote for an answer visible when you finish reading a post.  Restriction: be able to see the score of a post when you start reading it.  Proposed Solution: animated page elements that follow you around at the corner of your eye as you scroll down a post, following you, waiting for you to blink before pouncing.  Alternative Solution: stick duplicate vote controls  in/near the "author block", maybe without the current vote status.

Comment: I recreated my account on Meta.SE just to upvote this answer and protest this annoying change.

Answer (score 178):

Very very nice feature which came from the community and was instantly implemented. My compliments for the speed in which it was implemented.

The feature in general works fine. I still have to get used to it a little and sometimes its current working isn't really [intuitive](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/257924/245360).

Besides that: a lovely feature!

I wonder though why there is a baseline of 5%. Do you expect more users to vote? Why not make it easier to vote and see what happens then? Even if no one votes more than they do now, this is a useful feature to me.

Comment: I agree about the "not scrolling vote controls on your own posts," but I can't change it without invalidating the current experiment.  Based on the results, we might run another test where the controls always move.

Comment: @JarrodDixon Currently, the scroll is 57 to "I don't like. If it goes ahead, I hope I can disable." vs 44 "Nice feature.". I guess this speaks for itself.

Comment: @IsmaelMiguel Actually, it really doesn't speak for much of anything, because *those are not the numbers they are interested in.* They are interested in whether or not it increases voting. That is the goal of the experiment. It is *those* numbers that will speak to the success or failure of the experiment, not voting here. These votes aren't even required to be made by people who have even gotten to try it yet.

Comment: @KRyan They can be from people who would hate such ad-like feature. Like me. I have it and I wish I didn't.

Comment: @IsmaelMiguel That one person, or sixty-four people, hate it, would be irrelevant if it increases the quantity and/or quality of voting on this site, which is the purpose of the experiment, and would be the purpose of the feature if it is implemented for real. Improving voting improves the site, for millions of people, so no one's personal opinion one way or the other matters much at all compared to that. There will be userscripts to deactivate it if it works but you hate it, there are already userscripts to activate it if it doesn't work but someone wants it, and so on.

Comment: @KRyan Thanks a lot. Yes, I didn't read the entire page. I hope more users see that link.

Comment: @KRyan: I disagree with the underlying premise. On the site that I know best (Math) I find the voting on questions virtually meaningless and the voting on answers less than useful, and I see no reason to think that more votes would improve matters. The answers themselves and the comments under them are *vastly* more useful than the vote counts.

Comment: @BrianM.Scott The vote *counts* aren't too important; the *voting* is. The voting is how SE applies a sorting algorithm on answers, and why SE is a system that allows the quick, reliable, and consistent finding of answers to one's questions. Voting is how SE avoids noise and attempts to ensure that the best answers can always be found immediately. Without voting, that doesn't happen, and SE is no better at Q&A than a discussion forum – and discussion forums are not great places for Q&A. More voting improves the likelihood that the SE system will correctly pick out the best answer.

Comment: @KRyan: There is no reason to sort answers by vote count unless one thinks that the count is meaningful. In my experience this is less than clear. In particular, I simply do not agree that voting does all that much to identify the best answers.

Comment: @BrianM.Scott then you fundamentally disagree with the foundation of the site, and I wonder why you use it. Or I would, were it not obvious: you use it because it works. And whether you think so or not, it works because of voting.

Comment: @KRyan: I do indeed have a number of fundamental disagreements with the underlying philosophy. And your final sentence is at best an exaggeration: I don’t think that it works especially well as intended. Rather, I use it *faute de mieux*, because I enjoy helping people with mathematics, and to the best of my knowledge it’s the only site available that has a decent interface for mathematics.

Comment: For the record: a certain lack of votes, relative to earlier times, is rather perceived as a reason for mild concern on [math.se], as can be seen from several meta-posts there.

Comment: While it sticks around, it's taking up room that is otherwise unused and anyone saying "it's distracting" must be *very* easily distracted. It offers a small benefit, but there's no downside to it. Ship it!

Comment: @Archonic: There obviously *is* a downside to it, given the number of people who dislike it intensely. They don’t disappear just because you disagree with them.

Comment: @quid: Very mild concern, and not in all quarters.

Comment: @KRyan - The issue isn't that one-dimensional.  Sacrificing UX quality for an increase in voting quantity/quality is a risky proposition at best.  For the SE system to work it also needs to provide an experience that makes users want to keep using it.  Ignoring that aspect simply because a change is seen as having a positive impact on voting quality when viewed in a vacuum largely misses the point.  Nothing happens in a vacuum, and a pleasant, user-centric UX is just as important to sustained content-quality as voting quality/quantity.

Comment: @aroth Certainly true, but 56% (current voting) dislike in anonymous polling that may include people who haven't tried it is not the same as confirmation that they are "sacrificing UX quality" in the first place. Ultimately, this feature's worth is a question of how it affects content-quality, but that is very difficult to directly measure since so many other variables affect it. I was mostly responding to knee-jerk reactions and failures to understand how the underlying mechanisms of SE contribute to it's content-quality.

Comment: @KRyan: You mean *how the underlying mechanisms of SE are presumed to contribute to its content-quality*. That they make some positive contribution is not really in doubt, but the extent of that contribution is not clear and appears to vary across sites. And contrary to what a naïve user might naturally suppose, relying primarily on vote-counts to judge answers is a very bad idea.

Comment: @BrianM.Scott If relying primarily on vote-counts to judge answers to material you are unfamiliar with is a very bad idea on any particular SE site, that site is broken and has serious underlying problems that need to be addressed. The entire *point* is that the highest-rated answer (and, potentially, other similarly-highly-rated answers) are the best; if that's not true, then the entire system serves no purpose.

Comment: @KRyan: Serves no purpose? No, it simply doesn’t work as well as a naïve user might suppose – or, apparently, as well as you think (or perhaps would like to think) that it does. In Math.SE the problem is exacerbated by the fact that a question can have a variety of quite different answers that are good (i.e., useful) to different segments of the potential readership and cannot reasonably be expected to get comparable vote counts.

Comment: I think it's a nice feature, and the not-scrolling aspect of it doesn't really bother me. Obviously, it bothers others, so I think it should be switchable. It is very convenient for voting on a long answer. I feel that having the action buttons at the bottom is a great addition to any blog/post type of site - don't make me scroll back to the top just to do something I wouldn't normally do until I've reached the bottom.

Answer (score 94):

I think it feels weird that the controls don't move on my own posts. My initial reaction was that it was a bug, and I had to look it up on meta to find out that this was intended.

Even though I can't vote on my own posts, it's still useful to see my own score and it feels kind of jarring when suddenly one post is behaving differently.

Comment: I agree; consistency is more important than being clever here, especially since you have the voting buttons *at all* on your own poss (but you can't use them) -- people will reasonably wonder why the system *partially* adjusts for their posts but not *fully*.

Comment: I also found some inconsistency and the closest I came to localizing the behavior is that the vote counters that I had already voted on seemed to move while others that I had not voted on seemed static. On the very next question I examined the behavior was not repeated. Go figure.

Comment: This is a good point. If you can make the voting buttons stay put for our own posts, why not just *remove* them?

Comment: @RubberDuck: Because it is looks inconsistent and weird and it makes people wonder it other people can even vote on that answer they posted because there don't seem to be any voting buttons.

Comment: Latest variant will scroll the controls on your own posts, provided they are of sufficient length (I edited the question with the changes).

Answer (score 79):

I like this because I far too often forget to vote on lengthy posts because the buttons escape my view. I want to wait for the test to finish to say for sure how much this is actually needed, but I suspect the impact is going to be far from marginal.

That said, two things I'd *like* which would make this more awesome:

**Don't scroll when the post length is less than or equal to the height of the voting controls.**

I don't know how expensive that's going to be server-side since it would need to be known in advance, getting this from the client would be icky if even really possible. `data-postlen=`?

**Dim the controls when scrolling comes to rest for a second so folks can read, restore opacity when scrolling resumes**

I'd like to see how this alleviates some of the "crazy ass things are following me, man!" complaints that folks have, and *might* alleviate some of the distraction others have reported. They're made more subtle as you read, more prominent when the rest of the screen is moving.

---

I want to see the numbers on how much more voting we're seeing. I've *personally* found this useful several times today, but actual numbers are going to be interesting.

**Alternate**

Put up/down arrows at the bottom of posts, similar to how the links to close / flag are oriented (in fact, before them) - but again, I want to see how this test pans out.

Comment: Not only can I forget to vote at the end of a long post, but I often get to the end of a long post and ask myself "have I voted yet?".

Comment: (Yes I know voting before finishing reading a post is discouraged, but I sometimes read a post more than once.)

Comment: I would change this so there was reduced opacity while scrolling, then restore opacity when it stops

Comment: @humble.rumble I almost posted it that way. It's the "That thing is now where I'm reading, thus I'm distracted" thing that seems most important, nothing should actively get in the _way_ of you reading something as you scroll, and we'd hope you reach the end of something before you became interested in those controls.

Comment: #1 sounds good. #2 sounds completely backwards, I'm not sure what it would look like but any extra changes of appearance would make the feature even *more* distracting.

Comment: I think dimming/undimming would be worse. A color change out of the corner of my eye would be nearly impossible to ignore while ignoring an effectively static-at-the-top-of-screen arrows is much easier.

Comment: Putting the score at the top ("do I want to read this answer?") and the voting buttons at the bottom ("now that I have read this, what do I think?") seems like a MUCH better solution to the "problem" identified. The voting buttons chasing you around are definitely not the way to go.

Answer (score 44):

I think the biggest thing I dislike about it is that when I am reading a post, something is moving next to me and is distracting.

Especially for longer posts this can be a bit annoying as they normally require more concentration.

That being said...

> This will run for another three weekdays, so it should finish up next Wednesday, 2015-06-10.

There will always be resistance to changes, perhaps consider running this a bit longer than just a few weekdays to get a better feel (unless preliminary voting numbers make it clear immediately).

Comment: Since only half of users currently see the new way, the test could be repeated with the other half without subjecting the current half to any more.

Comment: What we need to look at here primarily is what effect it's having on voting, nothing is yet set in stone - this is just a test of a hypothesis and request for feedback on it. Depending on how the test goes, we might implement some changes and ask folks to try it again for a short time, or we might say "not a good idea". Scrolling vote buttons also don't come close to the Google + / Youtube thing, let's keep this grounded?

Comment: @TimPost that's why I suggest running it even longer than a few weekdays ;)

Comment: @enderland Well, since we don't know the outcome in advance and a _negative_ dip in voting is possible, that's not something we want to risk for more than a short amount of time because of how tightly voting is coupled to continued participation. On this iteration, we'd rather incorporate feedback to make people feel better about it overall, and (likely) try again soon. We have to see the results to really be sure, I hate to sound so speculative but, well, that's the nature of tests :)

Comment: @TimPost `unless preliminary voting numbers make it clear immediately` -- totally agree there.

Answer (score 37):

I've provided feedback in a separate [post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/257978/dont-move-vote-buttons-past-bottom-of-the-text-in-a-post) but I'll move it here to keep everything tidy.

---

This is related to the previous feature of not [moving vote buttons past the bottom of the post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/257910/dont-move-vote-buttons-past-the-bottom-of-the-post).

I'd like to request that the "bottom" of a post be redefined to be the *bottom of the text* and not include the user card. On short posts, the user card introduces unnecessary scrolling.

---

For example:

This [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30667426/189134) is smaller than the size of the vote/score buttons:

[image: Unscrolled Answer]

If, however, I scroll down to start reading the other answers, the buttons follow just enough to be distracted by the moving UI component. It follows to the bottom of the user card.

[image: Scrolled Answer]

Notice that the buttons on the above image followed me down to the "add comment" (just below the user card).

The stickiness is nice on long posts (like the question portion of the link above), but several of the answers are short and the stickiness is distracting when it occurs unnecessarily. I think this can be resolved by only keeping the buttons sticky within the size of the answer text and not including the user card.

Comment: There is always going to be a number of lines that initiates the dynamic behavior whether it be one line, two lines or more. Consistent behavior is important too and acclimates the user to the vote counter movement.

Comment: It seems like a rule like "don't move it if the post fits on your screen" might help. I'm in the control group, though, so I don't really know.

Comment: I agree and the latest variant makes the voting buttons not descend lower than the bottom of the post text.

Answer (score 25):

I think StackExchange is great regardless of this feature (I am neither against it, nor in favour of it), but if you are going to implement it, at least consider fixing this bug.

On my smartphone (in my case an iPhone 5c, running iOS 8.3, latest as of June 6th 2015 - but I think this is related to screen size rather than specific device) the vote buttons are moving over the post when zoomed in. This is bad, because it makes both the vote count and - perhaps more importantly - the post itself hard to read.

Image of bug (top status bar cut off):

[image: picture of random post demonstrating the bug described above]

**Edit**: I forgot to include the solution I would propose: let the vote count go off-screen (i.e. only change y position (relative to the page, not the screen) and preserve the x position (also relative to the page).

If another solution is found preferable, I'm fine with that too. I proposed a solution only because I think it's better to say "I don't like X, maybe Y is a solution" than to just state "grrr I hate X".

Comment: This also happens when using a low screen resolution: http://i.imgur.com/9jwV3TS.gif

Comment: Disabled for mobile devices, not just the mobile theme.  @cybermonkey in the (unlikely) event the experiment is successful, I would fix that bug, but...  it looks to be kinda complex for something that'll run another day or two.  I'd have to watch for horizontal scrolling and offset the fixed position (I think).

Comment: @JarrodDixon eww, just use sticky

Comment: @bjb568 I wish I could, but it's [not supported in Chrome](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/position#Browser_compatibility) (after [v35](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15646747/why-doesnt-position-sticky-work-in-chrom)), which is our largest browser.

Comment: @JarrodDixon meh, the feature doesn't seem to matter very much, so maybe it could just be disabled on Chrome. Without sticky, everything is just buggy or hacky. A horizontal offset wouldn't look smooth.

Answer (score 22):

How are you going to analyze the results of the A/B testing?

One problem that may arise is that people will be voting by accident on the wrong answer, because two sets of controls will be right next to each other.

Some of them will notice the mistake, un-vote, and then vote again on the correct answer. This is something that you can track without much effort. But some of the people won't notice it, and this is something that you won't be able to track.

[image]

Comment: I don't understand this. The floating buttons make it *less* likely to accidentally vote for the wrong answer. That reason is why I kind of like this change despite my low intolerance for visual effects.

Comment: @Gilles they really don't. When they have a fixed position they enhance the visual break between answers, you can clearly see where the next answer begins. But this way they blur the break.

Comment: I don't understand what potential for error you're seeing. The floating buttons are always on-screen and always next to the answer, so they're easy to find. With top buttons, I've learned to be careful of accidentally voting on the answer above the long answer I meant to vote for, because when I'm scrolling back up, I might miss the separation between answers, especially when the answer above has no comments.

Comment: In the screenshot above, I'm afraid they'd accidentally downvote the top answer instead of upvoting the bottom one.

Comment: Why? Because they're used to the voting buttons being too far up? With the change, the buttons are no longer too far up, so that's only a problem in the transition, it isn't an argument against the new positioning.

Comment: Haha, if only there were an accurate way to track how many votes go on wrong answers!

Comment: @DavidWallace SELECT Count(*) WHERE VoteType = Upvote

Comment: I think there should be ample space between answers; additional bottom padding was just added and they [no longer descend into comments](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/257910/dont-move-vote-buttons-past-the-bottom-of-the-post), unlike the animated gif.

Comment: @JarrodDixon It's much better now, thanks!

Comment: Mmm, that screenshot looks like Meta, even though the OP says the A/B test only runs on Stack Overflow... Is that screenshot actually showing the new feature?

Answer (score 22):

I am apparently part of the split/test of the new widgets and I was directed here from my post on meta.stackoverflow regarding the moving vote widget. [**Moving animated vote counter widget, can animation be configured off?**](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/296123/moving-animated-vote-counter-widget-can-the-animation-be-user-configured-off?noredirect=1#comment203225_296123)

Here is the sum and substance of the question/discussion regarding the widget and a suggestion that there should be some way for users to disable the moving object on a per-user-basis. Some may love them, others may want to pick up a hammer and permanently fix it. (a configuration option in between is probably a happy medium):

In the past day or two, the little vote widget for questions has started following the question up and down the window for the extent of the question. If it is a long question, that little widget becomes quite annoying.

While I'm all for improvement, I caution against adding all the latest 'gee-whiz' animated bells and whistles just because you can. SO is clean and non-intrusive. The more animated widgets get added, the closer the site moves to the dividing line between **clean/enjoyable** and **annoying/distracting**. The line is different for all users, and I'll admit that I prefer a clean usable interface without animated distractions.

This isn't a complaint saying remove it, but rather a suggestion that animated parts of the site have some type of user-preference that allows users who find the moving widgets annoying to simply -- turn them off. (or disable moving animations, or something similar)

The script features that update your comment inbox, etc. are all perfectly fine, they provide no distraction because they don't move. Having the vote counter flittering up/down the left side of the browser window is something I would like to turn off. Recognizing others may love it and think it is the greatest thing since sliced-bread, don't de-animate it, but please find a way to allow users to turn it off.

Remember, somebody's latest gee-whiz feature, is a bug to someone else -- if it can't be turned off.  In the case of the **flittering widget**, on questions with long answers, it is horribly annoying to have the little controls racing down the screen as I scroll down.

Comment: I only read "The more animated widgets get added, the closer the site moves to the dividing line between clean/enjoyable and annoying/distracting. " and up-voted  'cause of that!

Comment: @MartinF and David - how is it "animated"?  I would say that something that sticks in the one place is the opposite of animated.

Comment: @SimonEast: The story (sticky buttons) was lost. The animation (supposed to illustrate the story) annoyed.

Answer (score 21):

I'm one of the lucky ones that have the new button behavior. And I don't like it.

At first I didn't know why I should care if this thingie moves around.
But I now realize that I have used the voting buttons as an highly visible divider between question and answer, and multiple answers.

When I read long questions I often scroll back and forth multiple times. Since I scroll in a quick manner, the voting indicators were a great way to know when I scrolled too far. That no longer works.

The voting indicators where also a great way to know when I scrolled to the top of an answer. Now I have to scroll to the previous answer, search for the tiny hair line between answers, or I have to observe when the voting buttons stop moving.

Once that thing is live, I will do whatever it takes to get rid of it. So please don't make that too hard.

Comment: This has been bothering me too, especially on very long answers with distinct sections - this morning I found myself wondering why an answer had such a crappy introduction before realizing that I'd scrolled a full half of it off the screen already.

Comment: @Shog9 I don't know if it would be a popular solution, but perhaps this could be helped by adding a heading to each answer so that it is easier to tell when the question starts regardless of where the voting widget is.

Answer (score 15):

For those “lucky” enough to be testing this, here is how you get rid of it. Note
I am using Firefox with Stylish. When you scroll a second `div` is created, and
if you stop the scrolling [on some answers](https://stackoverflow.com/a/91558) this second `div`
creates a space between the answer and the comments.

```css
.js-vote-sticky {
  position: static !important;
}
.js-vote-sticky + div {
  display: none !important;
}
```

[Source](http://github.com/svnpenn/dotfiles/blob/293916efe/firefox/public.css#L50-L55)

Comment: This will disable the effect, but not the unacceptable `scroll` and `resize` event handlers. I suggest hijacking `$.fn.stick_in_parent`: `Object.defineProperty($.fn,'stick_in_parent',{set:function(){},get:function(){return function(){return this}}});`

Answer (score 15):

Animation on websites annoys/angers me immensely.

If i want animation, i go to the TV or to YouTube.

If i want information, i go to sites (that don't have animation).

Comment: Disable CSS and you're set then...

Comment: And JavaScript. But you'll lose a lot of functionality in that case and without CSS many websites are very hard to use.

Comment: In other words, it's not a viable option, is it, @nico?

Comment: @MartinF I was just being sarcastic. You seem to be confusing content with presentation. Information is there whether there are animations or not. The vote arrows don't move around all the time (now, that would be annoying), they just move along as you scroll. While reading a long answer you will not be scrolling all the time, so the arrows will not be animated and will not distract you from reading the content.

Comment: I have no idea what you, or anyone else, is saying about voting arrows -- that message is lost *completely*, thanks to the annoying animation.

Comment: Didn't you hear? [Stack Overflow is a TV station now!](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/270574/560648) As such, your argument is invalid. ;)

Answer (score 13):

I've been put in the group with the sticky vote controls.

I've learned today that I rely on those vote controls to indicate the structure of the page to me. In particular they indicate the top of the question and each answer. They're like the bullet points on a list, on a page that is just a really big list. If they're moving around, I lose the structure I depend on to make sense of things.

- If I'm busy scrolling, I no longer have a sense of how many answers I've been past and where on the page they are located.
- If I stop scrolling in the middle of a large answer and I'd like to read it, my ability to locate the top of that answer is currently impaired. I usually scroll up until I see the voting controls. Instead I scroll up until they stop moving, and then re-orient. If I'm scrolling too fast, I might confuse those voting controls with those of the *previous* answer for a moment before realising my mistake. (They're right there at the top left where I'm focusing, after all.)

It's actually surprising how disorienting it is. The pages lose the key dependable structural element I have apparently learned to depend on heavily. And I scroll and skim fast through answers, so this is a big impairment for me.

Call it adjustment, certainly. I've built a mental model for rapidly navigating Q&A pages and I'll have to *rebuild* it. But that is going to take some serious adjustment.

I would prefer not to have sticky vote controls. I like my bullet-point vote controls.

Comment: OK this is a fair point, interesting

Answer (score 11):

I don't mind it scrolling vertically, although it was a bit unsettling at first. But *please* don't scroll horizontally! I browse with a large text size, so sometimes need to scroll horizontally, and the vote buttons follow me across the screen, obscuring whatever text of the question/answer is in the top-left corner.

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/258128

Answer (score 9):

I'm finding it disorienting.

The "vote" buttons behave "unpredictably", visually.

As I'm scrolling down, some of them are moving "up", but one is staying still at the top of the page, until suddenly it pops off the top, to be replaced by another.

No, thanks.

Comment: It bothers me that some of the buttons scroll with the answers but others don't.

Answer (score 7):

I find this *extremely* annoying. I don't want to see it. Ever. Not only do I not care about the score of a post while I'm reading it I think it begs for votes way too much. Not to mention being terribly distracting.

If I want to vote I can scroll up the page some. I think a much better solution would be to add mostly transparent "go to top of answer" buttons at the bottom of really long posts. Or, if you could do it unobtrusively, detect if I am rapidly scrolling and add both bottom and top buttons next to the text (again, mostly transparent so it isn't as jarring), but I'm not sure if that would have the same terrible annoyance of the current proposal.

Comment: Or put the vote buttons at the bottom always.

Comment: That seems a bit extreme..  Radical change, but I guess it does make some sense.

Answer (score 6):

> I agree about the "not scrolling vote controls on your own posts," but
>   I can't change it without invalidating the current experiment. Based
>   on the results, we might run another test where the controls always
>   move. –  Jarrod Dixon

Evidently I'm not in the variant group (I'm not seeing any change) but I support the original suggestion that we locate the voting buttons in a fixed position at the foot of the post. I'd like to see the score alongside them, but also remain at the top of the post (without necessarily having voting buttons there). I suggest this arrangement for two reasons:

- It makes sense to have actually read the post before voting, while
- It also remains useful to be aware of how others have voted before reading.

From a quick scan of remarks by others here and elsewhere, I see I'm not alone in being not at all keen on the idea of things moving around.

So, with the comment I've quoted from @Jarrod Dixon in mind, can we please also have a test where the controls never move? And a vote on the final choice about any movement, after we've *all* had a chance to try out the different ways?

Comment: There will always be some posts for which it is appropriate to vote before finishing reading (obvious low quality/spam) but that's also a reason to have a flag option at the top too.

Comment: @trichoplax I take your point and I've edited my answer slightly to allow the possibility of keeping buttons at the top too,

Answer (score 6):

I don't care actually. If answer is good and helped me — I vote it up, regardless where these buttons are.

Answer (score 5):

Works on this, https://stackoverflow.com/q/30673961/1927206

Does it *need* to move around on posts of that size? I was confused. If it had been a post which went off the end of the page, so the voting mechanism needed to move at some point, I'd have probably worked out the purpose.

There are probably going to be at least two camps on this. My camp is "only move when needed", by the length of post (if possible, I have no clue) and ability to vote.

If you are analysing whether this generates more votes than otherwise, I think you should separate the "short" posts from the "long" ones. You'd not really expect more votes when the movement wasn't needed, presumably the intent is to get more votes for longer posts by making it (physically) easier to vote on those?

Are there really enough "long" posts to have an impact?

And, is it my imagination, or does the voting scroll into the comments in the mock-up in the question? That would be bad.

That would be bad, why? Someone or someones are going to "vote" on a comment they like. Sometimes they'll realise (then, or at some later point). Sometimes they won't.

Comment: No - they don't go down into the comments: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/257910/dont-move-vote-buttons-past-the-bottom-of-the-post. The only reason they're in the gif is because the gif was from my answer (which did go into the comments)!

Comment: @ᔕᖺᘎᕊ Yes, I know they don't, but they do on the image in this question, and on one of the linked questions someone says it would be good if they were there in the comments. I therefore want to get my retaliation in early. Now I see from your link that my retaliation is late, but I'll leave it to potentially deter naysayers.

Comment: A minimum height requirement has been added.

Answer (score 5):

I think this feature is not bad per se, but weighting the pros and cons and the main goal, I would prefer an option like the alternate in TimPost's answer or the first part of LadybugKiller's answer [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/35047/295117).

Something moving (or animated) distracts me a lot and avoids me to concentrate in what I'm reading.

As the main goal is to increase the amount of votes (up or down) while doing it easier (without scrolling up and down after every answer), that could be achieved without moving the vote controls:

1- If the answer if short enough, I don't need to scroll (I still see this control on my screen), so it isn't needed to move it.

2- If the answer is long enough, a repeated control in the lower part would do the job without any harm.

If you want not a repeated control, **just show it at the lower part of every answer**, as it would be very uncommon to vote an answer while reading just the upper part.

Comment: Score at top, vote buttons at bottom. Would be cool.

Answer (score 4):

Could the distance the votes stay from the top of my screen be the same as the distance between the vote and grey seperator when it's not scrolled?

This is the distance I would like it to be - from the faint grey line to the point of the upvote. I make it 50 px from the line to the point:

[image]

But closer to 70 from the window top to the point:

[image]

Please can these be the same?

Comment: You bookmarked Google?

Comment: @bjb568 yes yes :P There was a reason for it many years ago I think

Answer (score 4):

I think it'll be cool if deployed for Desktop Users. It must be added as an additional feature. It can be a bit annoying for Mobile Users as I too use SO and other sites through my phone and the floating vote button will hinder my experience on the small screen size.

When thinking on a large scale, I think there would be plenty of users who uses SO through their mobile and tablet devices with each one having a different screen size. So, even if you introduce it, you'll be playing around with live users. I think SO is just fine as it is now.

Answer (score 3):

It would make sense to put duplicate vote/accept buttons at the bottom of a very long post, so you don't have to scroll several screens back up to vote. Instead of them moving, of course.

Comment: What about posts that are very long which you want to check the vote while in the middle of reading it?  If you scroll up/down looking for the vote box there, then you will loose your place.

Comment: Pro tip: select the text with cursor, and even when you scroll the page it stays selected.

Comment: Yes, unless you are doing that already or are not a pro. :)  I had a similar opinion when I first saw the change, but phase 2 seems to have fixed my issues while being easier to implement, maintain, and use than the multiple vote system.  Does phase 2 still bother you?

Answer (score 2):

I am not sure how much effort it would be to implement this conditionally, but Firefox natively supports this via CSS. Something like the below CSS would be able to replace the JQuery library and the JS code in Firefox.

```css
.vote {
  position : sticky;
  top : 0;
}
```

So why not simply let the browser handle all the processing and code to get the same behavior?

Comment: See http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/257927

Answer (score 2):

Scrolling vote buttons make it much easier to read the first (long) answer, vote, and then continue to other answers.

This would be especially useful on sites like Worldbuilding, where many answers have pieces of the complete solution. I find myself scrolling up a whole screen to vote, then back down to read the next answer.

Answer (score 2):

Thank you for not making it "smooth scroll" like most auto scrolling advertisements are. It looks like a nice feature, but for small and simple posts (like this answer will likely be), it feels very weird to have a small element remain fixed and then move instantly.

Can we have it turned off if the rendered length of the post is like half of the screen or less?

Answer (score 2):

I like the stickiness; it's convenient and I harbor none of the *"omg, it's following me"* reservations raised by other users. That said, I'm not too keen on this particular line-item:

> - stickiness is applied if the post's body is longer than 2/3 of the browser window's viewport

What problem was this attempting to address? All it seems to do is introduce inconsistent behavior.

Comment: It's to prevent needless movement on pages where none is required. I really like it, YMMV.

Comment: "We're into the next variant with these changes, based on feedback:" and the feedback is in the answers.

Answer (score 2):

I haven't gotten a chance to try this, it seems like it could be useful, but instead of following why not just permanently fix all vote buttons to the bottom of the post instead of the top? You're expected to read the post anyway before voting (at least I think you are), so it seems to address the "I don't feel like scrolling up" premise without the stickiness that some find irritating. On the other hand it's useful to have the score at the top so maybe this <s>comment</s> answer isn't the greatest idea. But people whine about score affecting votes anyways, so maybe score fixed to top, buttons bottom...

I think this would be a simpler way to address the identified issue, plus some.

Comment: You want the score at the top and middle to answer the "Is this worth reading?" and "Is this essay worth finishing?" questions.

Comment: @Trisped Maybe something like: Score at top (is this worth reading?), nothing in middle (if somebody's halfway through hopefully they have enough capacity for independent thought to decide if it's worth finishing without checking the score again), buttons at bottom (read *then* vote). I think. I dunno.

Answer (score 1):

I noticed this yesterday, while working on an answer, including that my own answer votes arrows would be fixed. It looked nice.

I cannot reproduce this functionality anymore, it is kind of confusing to not be permanently in the variant group.

Comment: I now have two Tabs open on different questions on [so] and for one this works, and for the other it doesn't. The confusing^2

Answer (score 1):

Why not make it an option? As for me, I'll grab it immediately!

Answer (score 1):

When there are many comments, and you scroll past the post to see the comments, the vote icon should not follow you past the post.

Besides that the only thing I don't like about it is that it does add complexity (more for the user to think about), and if you add a switch to turn it off, that would add complexity as well. Obviously we have to balance the overall complexity of the system with the overall featureset.

Answer (score 1):

It is much easier to deal with now (phase 2).  Phase 1 I wanted to scream, now I do not even notice it.

Answer (score 1):

Just to report a quick "bug" I found on this subject <sub>(not quiet sure if you guys already found this yet or not).</sub>

[image: Bug A/B]

So what you see is the votes of **question** (which has 0 votes) on top of votes of  the 1st and only **answer** (which has 3 votes).

This "bug" was found using FF38.0.5 with Win7

Despite this, so far, I like the new sticky votes, although I think in a UX point of view (IMO) the old way is better.

Answer (score 0):

Having control buttons in a fixed position is something quite common on today's web experience. You see the top navigation bar fixed at the top of a lot of news paper site and e-commerce sites. More annoying for some users (who don't use an AdBlock tool), is the fact that advertisement banners, usually on the right side of the page and not inline with content in some cases is fixed to the top while scrolling.

What is new here is that the buttons also fixes at the top of the page while scrolling downward in the same answer. These are inline controls and apart from sticky ads I think the experience from users will be positive, once you get used to it. It fix the problem scrolling back up to vote, and would probably improve the number of votes.

The con is that we are no longer looking at content in fixed position. This is especially true when asynchronous loading of pages mess up the current viewport and move what you're reading away. But the implementation here, doesn't do that cruel design choice. And we have been moving away from fixed pages since the introduction of scripted pages in the middle of the 1990s. This is another invention in that direction.

So from a UX perspective I believe it's a good thing where pros outrank cons.

Answer (score 0):

The vote buttons get lost in case there's a long list of comments, i.e. it does not scroll more downward than the length of the question or the answer.

I often read comments if available, because some of them have good points, and then vote. In case of a long list of comments, even with the new feature enabled, I have to scroll back to reach the controls.

If the vote buttons follows me, I'd expect them to follow more.

Comment: Deliberate change. Perhaps to avoid accidental voting for a "comment".

Answer (score -1):

That looks creepy! No doubt on that. I just started to see this and thought that either I need a sleep right now or SO implemented a new feature without telling us first.
Then I found this post. Well as feedback, I am sure this is a nice feature. I first saw this in my Windows Phone when the list of apps are scrolled the alphabets stick to the top and keeps changing whenever the new alphabet comes out.
That looked nice there, but frankly I felt creepy.
That's possibly because I didn't have enough sleep or because I am not used to this on SO. In logic that does look like a productive feature (you do not need to scroll long answers to vote.), but my eyes are not comfortable with it..yet.

So I would suggest as everyone has suggested to make this an option. You can check how many of the users have turned it off. So the benefit would be that the user will have an option to choose whatever they feel comfortable with and you will get the data of how many wants that feature. (Of course you will need a way to tell people about where is the setting to turn it off).

Personally I will turn it off for few weeks and then turn it on only when I am fully sober. So that my eyes doesn't feel the pain when they are most vulnerable.

Answer (score -2):

Please do not implement this or if you do then please allow an option to turn this off.  I would vote but I do not have enough reputation on this site.

Answer (score -4):

This is a very interesting idea. I'm not in the lucky testing group, but I've been thinking for a while that a change was needed to call out the voting more.

I think it would be even more interesting, effective, and fair, if you hid the vote counts behind an ellipsis or something similar and reveal on click. The answers would still be ordered by score, but it might reduce the likelihood that some users will upvote just because they liked an answer and it already has a high score, not knowing if it's truly correct. Ie, reducing "score bias".

Design-wise it looks uncomfortable to me in the animated example because it's floating and drawing the eye constantly on scroll. I'm imagining it might be more comfortable if it sat on, or next to a line and then disappeared into the 'share | edit | flag' line, which shouldn't be floating either.

I think if you introduce a sticky moving element, you need to carve up and visually define the structure more. The minimalism is too minimalist :) For example, with a border between the content and the vote counter here on meta, there would be a stable visual anchor at the start of each line. All speculative ideas.

Answer (score -5):

Here is a possibly more effective way to give feedback:

If you are in the testing group, and don't like the feature, I suspect the best way to voice your disapproval will be to abstain from voting while the test is running.

The metric (5% increased voting) could be weighted heavily in the website's final decision.  By abstaining from voting, you can send a message that the effect is not appreciated via a side channel.

Similarly, if you are in the testing group and like it, vote with abandon.