# Sticky votes should adapt to zoom

Tags: bug, voting, user-interface

I've noticed that the "Sticky vote" count is defective when a certain page contains horizontal scrolling -when it's zoomed in, for example- because the vote count overlays the text of the question, as you may see in this image:

---

[image]

Comment: AFAIK zooming is not supported...

Comment: @rene Do you mean it should be tagged with "feature-request" rather than "bug"?

Comment: I wouldn't do that because I expect not many users would want that feature. bug is fine I guess, I'm only saying so to get you prepared for a [tag:status-by-design]...but maybe the new css-design makes zooming possible. I would wait for a dev to respond.

Comment: Isn't it rather an issue with horizontal scrolling than zoom? (Though zooming in may make it scrollable in the first place.)

Comment: This looks like an issue with horizontal scrolling rather than specifically zooming. If your browser has a narrow width causing horizontal scrolling (e.g., from window tiling), the `position: fixed` vote controls will render above the post when scrolled horizontally.

Comment: Closing this because the sticky vote controls feature [has been removed again](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/258048/a-b-testing-the-sticky-vote-controls-give-your-feedback-please). Thanks for the report though.