# Chrome scrolling bug on Stack Overflow

Tags: bug, design, google-chrome

It's hard to describe, but the `votecell` `<td>` tag can overlay the questions/answers in chrome. It is clear this is not on purpose as it only occurs in chrome (tested in IE and Firefox). Here's an image to show what I mean:

[image]

To recreate this, resize your window horizontally until a scroll bar is shown. Then simply scroll right and then up/down the page.

I am using "Chrome Version 43.0.2357.81 m."

So onto the question: is this the same for everyone else with this version of chrome? Will this be fixed?

**Edit:** While the other question produces the same error, my browser is not zoomed in. This happens regardless of zoom.

Comment: Same for me, with version 42.0.2311.152. I left an answer in the designated feedback thread: http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/258131/158566