# Moderator "n deleted comments" control doesn't stay attached to its post when you expand comments

Tags: bug, status-norepro, comments, design, moderator-tools

Before expanding comments on [the question](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/21427/why-do-the-subtitles-say-tetsusaiga-for-tessaiga), there is a "1 deleted comment" widget next to the accepted answer:

[image]

When I expand the comments on the question ("show 5 more comments"), the widget stays in the same position on the page, rather than scrolling with the accepted answer:

[image]

This is slightly confusing and it would be nice if this didn't happen. I have not seen this behavior before today, so I suspect it could be related to [the sticky vote controls A/B test](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/258048/) (but then again, maybe I just haven't performed this sequence of steps before).

Comment: I cannot reproduce this even after re-enabling sticky vote controls (that experiment was cancelled, so if this *was* related, the problem would've fixed itself). Are you still seeing this? What browser are you using?

Comment: @balpha I no longer see this. [status-norepro], I guess.