# Android App Text Encoding Bug (Unicode Symbols don't Display Properly)

Tags: bug, android-app, unicode

Stack Exchange Android App
Version 1.0.63

Samsung Galaxy S4
SPH-L7200T
Android 5.0.1 Lollipop

There is a pretty odd bug I noticed today with the Stack Exchange App: certain Unicode strings do not appear properly.

[image: Question/Answer Text Bug]

As you can see in the preceeding screenshot, the text `ᔕᖺᘎᕊ` does not appear properly. This issue is not limited to just the Question and Answer text bodies, but also usernames.
 The characters appear as the general invalid replacement character.

[image: Username Text Bug]

This issue makes it impossible to perform certain tasks. (Like tagging the aforementioned user.) I had to post this question from my desktop as the app won't properly copy/paste the user's name.

I'm curious if this isn't a font issue, though I have switched to the various fonts available on my device and none of them have fixed it. That said, when I edited this question from my Android device, it still correctly saved the username included above back to the database, which would indicate a font issue.

Also, and unrelated, the `ask question icon` is a tad blurry in the Android App, though this is beyond the main scope of this question.

Comment: This isn't the apps problem - the font used for my username (and other Unicode symbols) are not installed on any (I think) Android phones - sorry for me being a pain, but I'm not going to change my (awesome :P) username :D And this is a dupe btw - I remember seeing someone reporting this (my username as their example as well!) - I just can't find it!

Comment: It's not just your name - many Unicode symbols have the same effect.

Comment: I understand - I'm just saying that it's not the app's *fault* - Android phones just don't have the font - the Unicode symbols work on iPhones for example...

Comment: WP8.1 supports them, too...

Comment: @ᔕᖺᘎᕊ Perhaps there is a workaround that SE can use to make them work. It's a pain in the arse (and is in fact one of two reasons I don't use the app exclusively) to work with, especially with as many SO users as there are that have characters outside the normal Unicode range in their names.

Comment: @ᔕᖺᘎᕊ Not to sound like a prick (just pointing out a technicality), technically, it **is** the app's fault. The app transmits the characters to the user with the expectation that they will be properly displayed by the device. If such an expectation cannot be met, then the app should *make some attempt* to sanitize the data before it reaches the user. (Granted, this is not necessarily the best choice in this situation.) And, while I don't recommend it, one fix would be to disallow certain Unicode characters in certain areas.

Comment: I have no idea what any of that means - but how would we expect SE to understand what certain text means!? Definitely wouldn't want SE to disallow certain Unicode characters - what would happen to me!?!?

Comment: @ᔕᖺᘎᕊ Unfortunately that's what makes it a painful choice.

Comment: Unfortunately, ᔕᖺᘎᕊ is right that it's not the app's fault. Nexus 5, Android 6.0.1, SE app v1.0.82 (beta) could show his/her username correctly. The same Unicode problem also happen on Chrome for Windows, not only on Android app. If you're still trying to find an acceptable font, you may consider [Noto](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Noto_fonts)